# Validate generics find query by runtime validator

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, zod

I'm creating an API where I can find user clients in NestJs (Typescript). I have this code:

```
export type LessThanOp = { $lt: number }
export type EqualOp = { $eq: string }
export type NotOp = { $not: string | Operator }
export type Operator = LessThanOp | EqualOp | NotOp | MoreThanOp

export type QueryWhereValue<T> = T | Operator
export type QueryWhereAnd<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends object ? QueryWhere<T[K]> : QueryWhereValue<T[K]> }
export type QueryWhereOr<T> = QueryWhereAnd<T>[]
export type QueryWhere<T> = QueryWhereAnd<T> | QueryWhereOr<T>

export type QuerySelect<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends object ? QuerySelect<T[K]> : boolean }
export type QueryPagination = { skip?: number, take?: number }

export type QueryOneOptions<T> = {
    select?: QuerySelect<T>
    where?: QueryWhere<T>
}

export type QueryOptions<T> = QueryOneOptions<T> & QueryPagination
```

I tried creating schemas with Zod, but the problem arises when I attempt to create QueryWhereSchema. What could be the best solution in this case? Any other validation library would also be fine.